# Does the kernel of a positive linear functional have a left identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let $\omega$ be a positive linear functional on a $*$-algebra $A$ with identity $1$,
and let $\ker(\omega) = \{x\in A:\omega(x) = 0\}$ be the kernel of $\omega$.

Does $\ker(\omega)$ have a left identity, i.e.,
does there exist an element $e$ in $\ker(\omega)$ such that $xe = x$ for each $x$ in $\ker(\omega)$?

And if not in general, are there any mild conditions under which this would be the case?

So far, it seems to me that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for positive linear functionals, and the fact that $\{x\in A:\omega(x^*x)=0\}$ is a left ideal, is related to my question, but does not really get me further (or at least I did not manage ;)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $C[0,1]$ and the positive linear functional $f \to \int f(x)\, dx$. Its kernel does not contain the identity.

Comment: It is easy to see that if $g$ is a (left) identity in the kernel then we must have $g(x)=1$ for all $x$ in which case $\int g(x)\, dx \neq 0$.